# Work on some partition from multiple

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file which has around `4264k` records. I am splitting the records in *5* partitions and want to select first partition for processing. How can I achieve that?

```
rdd = sc.textFile("file:///user/somelocation/a.txt", 5)
```

How can the first partition be selected for further processing?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve - accessing an arbitrary partition is not the usual way to work with Spark

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to see/process data of a particular partition.

In below example I extracted partition 2 data.

```
val rd =  sc.parallelize((1 to 100), 4) // created an rdd of 1 to 100 numbers in 4 partitions

rd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((index, iter) => Iterator((index,iter.toList)), true) // mapping partitions with its index
    .filter(x => x._1 == 2) // filtering only 2 nd partition 
    .collect.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(2,List(51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75))  // partition number followed by List of values in the partition
```